# how to update indexeddb store items with dexie

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have Indexed db table

```js
    "00014381104394"    
{id: "00014381104394", name: "A House Divided: Season 1 (DVD)", productimg: "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/99cfec5c-634e-4e26…4465.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", unitofissue: "each", quantity: 1, …}
1   "00016500590958"    
{id: "00016500590958", name: "One A Day Men's 50+ Mini Gels, Multivitamins for Men, 80 Ct", productimg: "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/7d44d419-bd6f-4808…b7ea.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", unitofissue: "each", quantity: 1, …}
2   "00022141041599"    
{id: "00022141041599", name: "Mepps Dressed Aglia Inline Spinner, Silver & Gray, 1/4 oz", productimg: "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a0ce2579-300a-4536…0d63.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", unitofissue: "each", quantity: 1, …}
3   "00038257767124"    
{id: "00038257767124", name: "Hanes Men' Max Cushion Comfort Top B&T Crew Socks 6 Pack", productimg: "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/f439dc53-c905-45bb…3436.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", unitofissue: "each", quantity: 1, …}
4   "00041333002132"    
{id: "00041333002132", name: "Duracell Coppertop AAA Battery, Long Lasting Triple A Batteries, 24 Pack", productimg: "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/09b2aa97-6655-4422…2259d.png?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", unitofissue: "each", quantity: 1, …}
```

i need to update the each item's quantity so I tried the code below

```js
db.cartitems.get(newItemId)
            .then((result) => { 
                 if (result){
                    db.table("cartitems").toArray().then((cartitemArry) => {
                         var cartitemArry1 = []
                        cartitemArry.forEach(product => {
                            if (product.id == newItemId){
    
                                 // increase item quantity
                                var qty = parseInt(product["quantity"])+1
                                product["quantity"] = qty

                                console.log(product.id," was found in cart. Qty increased from ",qty, "to ", product["quantity"])
                                 
                                cartitemArry1.push(product)
                                console.log("cart array push at ",newItemId,"\n", cartitemArry1)


    
                            }else{
                                cartitemArry1.push(product)
                            }
                            console.log("cart array", cartitemArry1)

                            
                        });
                         db.table('cartitems').bulkPut(cartitemArry1)
                            .then(() =>{
                                console.log('finished updating cart')
                            }).catch(error => {
                                console.log(error);
                            });

                       
                        resolve(cartitemArry1)
                     })
```

The above code fetches all items in table but does not save the updated quantity. I just want to be able to increase or decrease the quantity of a specified itemid.
I didn't know how to directly update the property of a specific itemid. So I fetch a desired item and then all items in the store and create a new array with all items in store to include the updated quantity of the desired item and then do a bulkPut to the same store with the new array. –
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to fetch all items when `db.cartitems.get(newItemId)` returns the one you want?

Comment: @charlietfl I pretty sure i'm doing it wrong.I didn't know how to directly update the property of a specific itemid. So fetch the item and then all items in the store and create a new array with the upated quantity and then do  I wanted to get the specific item and then do a bulkPut to the same store with the new array.

Comment: OK. Well `result` should be the single item that you would update (assuming it exists) and then rather than `bulkPut` just `put()`.  Check docs, I haven't looked at them for long time but am 95% sure it is just `put()` for a single item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to increment the "quantity" property of given newItemId in cartitems, do:

```
db.transaction('rw', db.cartitems, () => {
  return db.cartitems.get(newItemId).then(item => {
    ++item.quantity;
    return db.cartitems.put(item);
  });
});
```

You could also do this (which is equivalent to the snipped above):

```
db.cartitems.where({id: newItemId}).modify(item => ++item.quantity);
```

See docs:

[Table.get()](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.get())

[Table.put()](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.put())

[Collection.modify()](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.modify())